# Drawing multiple lines and remembering their thickness

Tags: android, path, drawing, hashmap, paint

It might be because I had a long day and it's quite late already, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I just want to be able to draw lines at my finger's position with each line to have a different width/color etc.

Whenever ACTION_DOWN gets fired I create a new `Path` and keep appending it at ACTION_MOVE. When ACTION_UP gets fired I put the current `Path` and `Paint` in my `HashMap`, thus saving which `Path` used which `Paint`, right?

When I call `setRadius(float radius)` from outside this class I call `paint.setStrokeWidth(radius)`, thus changing the current `Paint`'s stroke-width.

But for some reason every time I call `setStrokeWidth(radius)` **ALL** of my Map.Entry's change?? And thus resulting in **Every** `Paint`'s stroke-width to be the 'new' stroke-width and repainting everything with the new stroke-width.

It's probably very obvious but I just can't seem to find the mistake.

This is my DrawView.java.

```java
package com.example.paintandprint;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    Map<Path, Paint> pathMap = new HashMap<Path, Paint>();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        for (Map.Entry<Path, Paint> p : pathMap.entrySet()) {
            canvas.drawPath(p.getKey(), p.getValue());
        }

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path = new Path();
            path.reset();
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            pathMap.put(path, paint);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return paint.getStrokeWidth();
    }

    public void setRadius(float radius) {
        paint.setStrokeWidth(radius);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these lines:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    pathMap.put(path, paint);
    break;
```

What are you sending in "paint"???  Is it not a pointer to a structure that is filled with the preset values.  Isn't every pathMap.put sending the same pointer that points to the same data?  That is why if you change it once, you change it everywhere.

You need to create a new Paint for each pathMap.put you make and copy the current values of your class's paint to it.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    Paint newPaint = new Paint();
    newPaint.set(paint); //copies the values over from the current class's paint
    pathMap.put(path, newPaint);
    break;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - I've spent ages trying to work out how to change the width of a Paint object.